# How do I specify my WHERE conditions while using readUsingIndex method of Google Spanner

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I have the following code snippets from [Google Spanner docs](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/getting-started/java/#using_the_client_library_for)

How do I specify WHERE conditions in this?

*It appears to me as if we can do only a regular SELECT from this and WHERE conditions to be applied while iterating ResultSet.*

```java
static void readStoringIndex(DatabaseClient dbClient) {

  // We can read MarketingBudget also from the index since it stores a copy of MarketingBudget.

  try (ResultSet resultSet = dbClient

          .singleUse()
          .readUsingIndex(
              "Albums",
              "AlbumsByAlbumTitle2",
              KeySet.all(),
              Arrays.asList("AlbumId", "AlbumTitle", "MarketingBudget"))) {
    while (resultSet.next()) {
      System.out.printf(
          "%d %s %s\n",
          resultSet.getLong(0),
          resultSet.getString(1),
          resultSet.isNull("MarketingBudget") ? "NULL" : resultSet.getLong("MarketingBudget"));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, did the answer that I posted worked for you? If it worked please take a time to mark the correct answer.

Comment: @Juancki My query was specific to 'readUsingIndex' method's usage. You words are correct, but they are not pointing to my query. You are showing usage of  'executeQuery' method.

I have marked the correct answer. Please check.
And yes.. Thanks a lot for taking out time for my Query.
Will keep crossing paths at further Questions !!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `readUsingIndex` method, you filter the rows you want to read by specifying one or more index key values that you want to read.

Assume that the index `AlbumsByAlbumTitle2` contains the column `AlbumTitle` and you want to read the albums with titles '*Great album*' and '*Not so great album*'. Your call should then be like this:

```java
client
    .singleUse()
    .readUsingIndex(
        "Albums",
        "AlbumsByAlbumTitle2",
        KeySet.newBuilder()
            .addKey(Key.of("Great album"))
            .addKey(Key.of("Not so great album"))
            .build(),
        Arrays.asList("AlbumId", "AlbumTitle", "MarketingBudget"));
```

A `KeySet` could also be a range (begin/end) or a prefix. Note that when using the method `readUsingIndex`, you are specifying that you want to use the secondary index for filtering rows. This means that you cannot filter on any other columns than the columns in the secondary index.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to specify WHERE statements into your Secondary Indexes query you can do it switching to SQL language.

```
SELECT AlbumId, AlbumTitle, MarketingBudget
FROM Albums@{FORCE_INDEX=AlbumsByAlbumTitle2} AS s
WHERE s.AlbumTitle = "Go, Go, Go";
```

Here I will include the code from the Cloud Spanner documentation to [Query Using a Parameter](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/getting-started/java/#query_using_a_sql_parameter) to which I added the `WHERE` statement.

```java
static void queryWithParameter(DatabaseClient dbClient) {
  Statement statement =
      Statement.newBuilder(
              "SELECT AlbumId, AlbumTitle, MarketingBudget "
                  + "FROM Albums@{FORCE_INDEX=AlbumsByAlbumTitle2} AS s "
                  + "WHERE s.AlbumTitle = @title")
                  // here you add more conditionals statements
          .bind("title")
          .to("Go, Go, Go")
          .build();
  try (ResultSet resultSet = dbClient.singleUse().executeQuery(statement)) {
    while (resultSet.next()) {
      System.out.printf(
          "%d %s %s\n",
          resultSet.getLong("SingerId"),
          resultSet.getString("FirstName"),
          resultSet.getString("LastName"));
    }
  }
}
```

Other methods include:

- [Read data using the API](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/getting-started/java/#read_data_using_the_read_api)
- [Use a secondary index](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/getting-started/java/#use_a_secondary_index)
- [Retrieve data using read-only transactions](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/getting-started/java/#retrieve_data_using_read-only_transactions)

Comment: I modified my answer to include the Secondary Index Query of your example.